# Graphics Cards - Power State

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have an Nvidia Optimus laptop dual-booting Ubuntu for general use and Windows 7 for gaming.

I only want integrated graphics for Ubuntu, and when I run `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` the output is:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Skylake Halo GT2 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.0.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.0.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 11.0.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I assume this means the integrated card is running as desired, though I want to be sure that the Nvidia card is actually in a powered-down state, and that I do not need to install bumblebee.

Is this enough to be sure the card is off?

Comment: What you've shown seems to say that Intel is being used, but I recommend doing another check first. Search for an open the Additional Drivers app. If the Intel Graphics option is selected (or no NVIDIA option is selected), then the card should be unused. [edit] a screenshot of it into your question.